# Is it possible to create a python program, that can use google translate?

Tags: python, google-translate

Is it possible to create a python program, that can interact with Google's Translate?

I'm thinking of a way that firstly opens a .txt file, then reads the first line, then interacts with google translate and translates the word from a spesific language to a spesific language, then logs it into a different txt file.

Main question: Is it possible to make Python 3.3 interact with Google Translate?
Please tell me if I didn't explain myself enough.

Thank you,
Tharix

Comment: Googling for it tells me there is a python api for Google Translate - http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

Comment: wow, more downvotes... what did I do wrong this time

Comment: Maybe you forgot to google yourself before asking this question?

Comment: @marue, yeah i guess so :(, well atleast I got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google API python client supports the google translate and lets you translate from one language to another:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples%2Ftranslate

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use something more specific like google translate api :

[Google Api sample at google code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/translate/main.py)